# Word length vs hyperbolic length of curves on a hyperbolic surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Suppose S is a surface which admits a hyperbolic metric - by this I mean a complete Riemannian metric of constant negative curvature, with totally geodesic (possibly empty) boundary.

Fix some finite presentation of the fundamental group $$\pi_1(S) = \langle X\ |\ R \rangle.$$

For an element $g\in \pi_1(S)$, define the *word length* $|w|_X$, with respect to the generating set X, to be the minimum number of generators needed to express $w$ as a word in X.

Fact: Every homotopy class of curves in $S$ contains a unique geodesic.

Question: What's the relationship between the word length of $w$, and the hyperbolic length of the corresponding geodesic?

Comment: In group terms, define in any finitely generated group with given word metric, $c(g)$ as $\min_h|hgh^{-1}|$. Then in your setting the length of the geodesic defined by $w$ is comparable to $c(w)$. (All this is unrelated to the choice of relators. Only the choice of generators matters.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. There are lots of hyperbolic metrics on your surface, that don't change the group, and lots of presentations, that don't change the metric.  What kind of relationship are you looking for?

Comment: You are confusing/conflating **based homotopy classes** (aka elements of $G=\pi_1(S,x)$) and **free homotopy classes** (aka conjugacy classes in  $G$). Which do you really mean? If you mean **based homotopy classes** then the relation of the word length and the hyperbolic length is given by Milnor-Schwarz lemma.

Comment: @MoisheCohen isn't it true that free homotopy classes have a one-to-one correspondence with conjugacy classes of $\pi_1(S,x)$? And could you expand on the significance of the Milnor-Schwartz lemma in this case?

Comment: @3891780: 1. Yes, this is what I said in my comment. 2. I could, but it is unclear to me what your question really is. Are you talking about based or unbased (free) homotopy classes? Do you know what Milnor-Schwarz lemma is? Do you know about Morse lemma (stability of geodesics)?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I apologise for being vague (and having the memory of a goldfish). I'll try again: Suppose I pick some Riemannian metric of constant negative curvature on my surface, and fix the path metric induced by the Riemannian metric. Now suppose I have some geodesic curve $\gamma$. Then $\gamma$ corresponds to a unique conjugacy class in $\pi_1(S,x)$, is this right?...

Comment: ...Now I know that the M-S lemma implies the existence of a quasi-isometry between $\pi_1(S,x)$ with the word metric, and the universal cover of S with the pull-back of the path metric. What does this mean in my setting? I'd like to be able to state something along the lines of this: (having fixed a presentation of the fundamental group, including some generating set X,) if $[w_{\gamma}]$ is the conjugacy class corresponding to $\gamma$, then there exist constants A,K such that for any word $w$ in the conjugacy class, the word length satisfies $|w|_X \leq Al_h(\gamma) + K$.

Comment: ...where $l_h(\gamma)$ is the length of the geodesic $\gamma$ in my path metric

Comment: @3891780: No, that would be false. The correct statement is the one in Yves' comment: $A^{-1} l(\gamma) -K \le c(\gamma)\le A l(\gamma) + K$, where $c(\gamma)$ is the minimum of word-lengths of elements in the conjugacy class $[w_\gamma]$.